# How to properly install USB display driver for Fresco Logic FL2000DX on Ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu, drivers, display-settings, proprietary-drivers

I need to connect additional monitors on my computer and I get Fresco Logic FL2000DX USB display adapters. This adapters works perfect on Windows but I need to use on my development machine based on Ubuntu 16.04.

I find this on git hub: https://github.com/fresco-fl2000/fl2000 and try to install it but installation fail.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use Ubuntu 14 LTS instead of 16 LTS

This information is from https://github.com/fresco-fl2000/fl2000

> **On which kernel versions does this driver work?**
>
> This driver is tested on Ubuntu 14 LTS as well as some Android platforms with kernel version 3.10.x. This driver source might not compile on newer kernels (eg. 4.0 or above) because of the fast-moving API changes in the mainstream kernel. You might need to adapt it for your own use.

Comment: That mean I need to downgrade my Ubuntu?

Comment: Is there a way to recode this driver to work on 16 LTS?

Comment: @IvijanStefanStipić To get the driver work on Ubuntu 16 you need to compile a custom kernel from kernel.org . The 3.10.107 kernel version should work as motioned

Comment: No need to downgrade, just install an older kernel and select it in grub when booting up

Answer (score 6):

**Telling the full story so all the keywords will be included in my response for future searchability:**

I've been looking everywhere for a driver or chipset info for the unbranded "Mini HD USB 3.0 HDMI Adapter" for years. I finally dug though enough duck duck go results to find a page that claims it uses the Fresco logic USB display driver, which brought me here.

I was able to get the driver to work using Linux Mint 18.2 "Sonya" with `linux-headers-4.13.0-45-generic`, but the instructions on git hub were not perfect.

1. Clone the repository `git clone https://github.com/FrescoLogic/FL2000.git`   (If you don't have git installed you can install it with `sudo apt install git` )
2. Navigate to src: `cd FL2000/src/`
3. Run `make` (contrary to the instructions, you don't need to edit `KERNEL_PATH` as the bug was fixed)
4. Insert the module `sudo insmod fl2000.ko`
5. Change to sample `cd ../sample/`
6. Run `make`  (I got an error here, but was able to test the driver and see an image despite the error)
7. Run `sudo ./fltest 0`

This crashed the first time I ran it but worked when I re-ran it a second time. Running it a 3rd time, it hangs my system.

Rebooting with the device plugged into the USB port seems to help. It will work at first launch. However, during shutdown my system is unable to disconnect from it's built in RAMDrive and will hang, ctrl-alt-del will move it a few steps further, but then it hangs again forcing me to do a hard shutdown.

---

I'm not sure if fixing the error when running `make` in the sample directory `make: /opt/hi3798/arm-hisiv200-linux/bin/arm-hisiv200-linux-gnueabi-gcc: Command not found` would make this any more stable.

I googled and came across [this thread](https://github.com/FrescoLogic/FL2000/issues/5) saying I "need to add head file `<sys/ioctl.h>`"  -- I didn't know how to do that so I followed the recommendation in [this thread](https://github.com/FrescoLogic/FL2000/issues/5) mentioning I should install some gcc packages:

```
sudo apt-get install gcc-arm-none-eabi gcc-arm-linux-gnueabi
```

After installing, make progressed further, but I am now getting a `make:  /opt/hi3798/arm-hisiv200-linux/bin/arm-hisiv20/opt/hi3798/arm-hisiv200-linux/bin/arm-hisiv200-linux-gnueabi-gcc: Command not found` error.

Installing `ia32-libs` hasn't helped.

Comment: This is not the full driver, so even though it is able to display static images, something else is needed for it to work with display managers etc: https://github.com/FrescoLogic/FL2000/issues/12

Comment: Just a heads up to KDE users, during my installing and uninstalling of drivers to get this proof of concept working I lost the ability to grab and resize windows.  Apparently `kwin` got uninstalled somewhere along the way; `sudo apt install kwin` fixed it.

Comment: BTW, one good way to identify USB devices is to look at the vendor and device id (via `lsusb` or `dmesg`) and then google in the form `1234:5678`. Unbranded devices in particular often just keep the ids of the generic chips.

Comment: Have you managed to solve this?

Comment: @TripleS that depends on what you mean by 'solve' can I **properly** install the driver?: *yes*.  Does it work well / is it bug free / does it provide video?: *no*.

Comment: @virtualxtc if the driver doesn't support video it's useless.  I wanted to use the external device for 2nd screen, now it's works only on windows.

Comment: @TripleS, agreed. Fortunately it's open source so you could put a bounty on fixing it, but in all honesty, even the windows driver is a hack; you are better off buying a real video card as this one will never really play video well because it uses the USB frequency as it's clock sync.

Answer (score 6):

Just in case someone is still looking, it seems there is a clean-sheet [re-implementation of the driver](https://github.com/klogg/fl2000_drm), by klogg from opensource community.

Comment: Have you been able to get those drivers to work? I've followed the tutorial given by klogg and have been able to load them (i.e. they show up with $ lsmod), but no video input is detected.

Comment: No. Was only researching before ordering, and hoping to have at least 1 all-good report. I needed this for some desktop-as-headless-servers, but I solved my needs with another method (albeit more expensive one). I'd suggest reporting an issue on Github against the project. The project owner seems to be fairly active.