# Debian - Driver for USB-C Hub

Tags: debian, drivers

Im looking for drivers that support my USB-C to USB-C/2xUSB/HDMI hub.

lsusb lists 3 new entries when the hub is connected:

```
> Bus 002 Device 003: ID 04e8:a020 Samsung Electronics Co., Ltd USB3.0 Hub
> Bus 001 Device 007: ID 1d5c:5100 Fresco Logic Generic Billboard Device
> Bus 001 Device 003: ID 057e:2003 Nintendo Co., Ltd USB2.0 Hub
```

HDMI is currently not working. I assume this is the Fresco Logic chip.

How can i determine what chip is in there in order to know what i need to add to my system?
Im currently running debian testing.

Comment: Beside HDMI, did you fail to get the HUB working? What did you try?

Comment: The hub works fine (usb). I was hoping for a tipp (possible a non free package i am missing).

Comment: there was this related Q/A https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/386485/how-to-properly-install-usb-display-driver-for-fresco-logic-fl2000dx-on-ubuntu but as written it's probably not working anymore.